# Existence of a normal subgroup with finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

i need to prove that if G is a group and K is a subgroup of G such that   |[G:K]|=n>1 then there exists a subgroup N of K such that N is a normal subgroup with respect to G and [G:N]<(n!)+1.
I did manage to show the existence of N except the last condition of its index, but i cant understand why i could always find such N with a finite index without any assumption about G.

Comment: hint: consider the natural action of G on the left (or right) cosets of K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the transitive action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $K$ in G by left multiplication, this induces a homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow S_{[G:K]}$ with $ker(\phi)=\cap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$. Now let $N:=ker(\phi)$, hence $N$ is normal in $G$ and notice that $N \subset K$. Now, $G/N$ is a subgroup of $S_{[G:K]}$ by the first isomorphism theorem(you indentify $G/N$ with the image of $\phi$), hence its order divides $n!$ and in particular less than $n!$ and therefore less than $n!+1$.